# A synonym for "with the condition that", that makes clear my conditional statement

Tags: synonyms

I would like an alternative way to write the following statement

> I accept that my brother is a terrorist and condemn his actions with the condition that you accept that your father is a war criminal and you condemn his war crimes.

The obvious implication being, my condemnation is conditional.

Or is the phrase "with the condition that" correct and sufficient in this statement?

Comment: *Only if* is equivalent to "with the condition that."

Comment: In casual language you can simply say "I'll do X if you'll do Y."

Comment: @YosefBaskin I've rewritten their example to be more generic.

Comment: 'I accept that my brother is a terrorist' needs to be 'I will/would accept that my brother is a terrorist' or the like.

Comment: You could use "if and only if", or invest in some commas. But I think this question needs to be made more precise to meet site rules ("Can you rewrite this?" is off-topic both here and on Writing SE). What exactly is your problem? Do you think the existing version isn't conditional?

Comment: Why is it that you think this might be insufficient? I'm confused as to what exactly the question is.

Comment: @alphabet Well, simply that fact that an if clause in a conditional does not (necessarily) entail a condition of any sort.